How to remove "Must disconnect specified child" warning from xaml, and SVG view model binding
Given this xaml snippet:
<Button Width="36"
        Height="48">
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource BellFilledSvg}"/>
    
    <Viewbox Width="11"
             Height="11"
             Margin="0,0,0,2">

        <!--ContentControl shows "Must disconnect specified child from current parent warning -->
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding BellImage}" />
    </Viewbox>
</StackPanel>

This SVG icon entry:
<Viewbox x:Key="BellFilledSvg"
         x:Shared="False">
    <Grid>
        <Path Data="M12.5395 1.71364C10.9157 ..."
              Fill="{Binding Path=BorderBrush, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Border}}}" />
        <Path Data="M5.82343 12.9267C5.11919 ..."
              Fill="{Binding Path=BorderBrush, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Border}}}" />
        <Path Data="M12.5395 1.71364L13.2466 ...."
              Fill="Transparent" />
    </Grid>
</Viewbox>

And this viewmodel:
public class MainViewModel
{
    private object _bellImage;

    public object BellImage
    {
        get => _bellImage;
        set
        {
            SetValueAndRaisePropertyChanged(ref _bellImage, value);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Default constructor
    /// </summary>
    public MainViewModel()
    {                        
        BellImage = Application.Current.Resources["BellFilledSvg"];
    }
}

Two primary questions:

Am I managing this dynamic binding properly to change the bell image based on user actions
What would be the easiest way to get rid of the "Must disconnect specified child...." warning? it works fine at runtime, but i'm not sure there'll be issues down the road.


Using Application.Current.Resources in a view model looks wrong. The view model should not have any knowledge of view elements or an application and its resources. Besides that, it is unclear what {Binding bellImage} is. Is it supposed to be {Binding BellImage}?

@Clemens - The statement that a VM should not have any knowledge of an application or its resources is, IMO, incorrect. The VM should be independent of the view, which i achieve here. Simply put that I need to show a different SVG based on some property. There is not a good way to do that dynamically without binding. I could use a converter to this, but the icon has to come from somewhere. I'm open to other ways to do this.
It is supposed to be BellImage. That was a typo when simplifying the example.

I cannot reproduce.
